# apollo server RDS and aws lambda

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

I'm using the apollo-server-lambda module to create a lambda that connects to RDS database. The only way I can properly connect to the RDS is the following

```
    exports.graphqlHandler = function(event, context, callback) { 

     context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

     sequelize.authenticate()

    .then(() => {
     console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
     callback(null, "just stop!");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
      callback("error");
    });
```

How can I do this using the Apollo server lambda createHandler method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

someone answered my question on github issues.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
 context: ({ context, event }) => {
  context. callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
 }
})
```

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1479